# Trying to show pictures from Unsplash into a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I am trying to show some pics fetched from Unsplash using a UICollectionView. The idea is to show a Cell with the image and the author name.
At the moment I can only show the border of the cell and the author name, doesn't matter how I approach the problem I can't show the UIImage.
I have added printout everywhere (yes, I mentioned I am a  beginner...) and I can print the url string and the reference to the image object.
I wonder if it's a problem with how I display the UIImage within the UIImageView, if for some reason the UIImage is not ready yet when the View is drawn (I know I have to fetch it why can I print it then?).

here's my code:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController  {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        view.addSubview(titleView)
        view.addSubview(searchBarView)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        searchBarView.delegate = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        picsManager.delegate = self
        
        setupLayout()
        
        
        
    }
    
    var picsManager = PicsManager()
    var pics = PicsModel()
    
    func setupLayout() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            titleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            titleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            titleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),

            searchBarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            searchBarView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            searchBarView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            
//            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBarView.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        ])
        
    }
    
    let titleView: UILabel = {
        let tv = UILabel()
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // tv.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
        tv.font = UIFont(name: "Georgia-Italic", size: 44)
        tv.textColor = .systemBlue
        tv.textAlignment = .center
        tv.text = "Coins Live"
        tv.sizeToFit()
                
        return tv
    }()
    
    
    let searchBarView: UISearchBar = {
        let sb = UISearchBar()
        sb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sb.searchBarStyle = .default
        sb.placeholder = "Search..."
        sb.sizeToFit()
        sb.isTranslucent = false
        sb.showsCancelButton = false
                
        return sb
    }()
    
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                                           left: 10,
                                           bottom: 0,
                                           right: 10)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        
        return cv
    }()

    
}

//MARK: - Extension UICollectionView

extension ViewController:  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    // Dimensions of the cell
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
//        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 3.5, height: collectionView.frame.width / 3.5)
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 1.1, height: collectionView.frame.width / 1.1)
    }
    
    // How many cells
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pics.pics.count
        
    }

    // Details of each cell
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.picLabel.text = pics.pics[indexPath.item].getUserName
//        METHOD ONE
//        let url = URL(string: pics.pics[indexPath.item].smallPicUrl)!
//        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
//        let img = UIImage(data: data!)
//        cell.backgroundImageView.image = img
        
//        METHOD TWO
//        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
//            if error != nil {
//                print("Error")
//                return
//            }
//
//            if let data = data {
//                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    cell.backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: data))
//                    print("cellForItemAt \(indexPath.item) : \(self.pics.pics[indexPath.item].smallPicUrl)")
//                }
//            }
//        })
//
//        task.resume()
        
//        METHOD THREE
        let urlString = pics.pics[indexPath.item].smallPicUrl
        cell.configure(with: urlString)
      
        return cell
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    // Contents of the searchBar are sent, but only after a delay. This is to prevent sending
    // a request after every character. Better to wait until the user has finished typing.
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(self.reload(_:)), object: searchBar)
            perform(#selector(self.reload(_:)), with: searchBar, afterDelay: 0.5)
        }

        @objc func reload(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            guard let query = searchBar.text, query.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) != "" else {
                print("nothing to search")
                return
            }

            if let term = searchBar.searchTextField.text {
                picsManager.getPics(term)
            } else {
                print("Invalid query.")
            }
        }
}

extension ViewController: PicsManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdatePics(_ pics: PicsModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.pics = pics
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
//            print("~~~ ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ ~~~ ~~~")
//            print(pics.pics[0].smallPicUrl)
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

CollectionViewCell.swift

```
//
//  CollectionViewCell.swift
//  UIKit_ProgrammaticUI_SearchBar
//
//  Created by Matteo on 31/08/2021.
//

import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    //MARK: - Init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        setupLayout()
    }
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    lazy var roundedBackgroundView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        view.layer.borderWidth = 2
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemTeal.cgColor
        
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var picLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13)
        label.textColor = .systemIndigo
        
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        iv.layer.borderWidth = 2
        iv.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemTeal.cgColor
        
        return iv
    }()
    
}


//MARK: - Layout
extension CollectionViewCell {
    private func setupLayout() {
        // When configuring a view, you add any custom subview to self.contentView
        // Option + leftClick for more info!
        self.contentView.addSubview(roundedBackgroundView)
        roundedBackgroundView.addSubview(picLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            roundedBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            roundedBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
            roundedBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            roundedBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            
            picLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerXAnchor),
            picLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -15)
        ])
    }
    
    func configure(with urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { [weak self] data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self!.backgroundImageView.image = image
                print("~~~~~ ~~~~~ ~~~~~")
                print(self?.backgroundImageView.image ?? "nothing to print here...")
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

PicsManager.swift

```
//
//  PicsManager.swift
//  UIKit_ProgrammaticUI_SearchBar
//
//  Created by Matteo on 01/09/2021.
//

import Foundation

protocol PicsManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdatePics(_ pics: PicsModel)
}

struct PicsManager {
    
    var currentPage: Int = 1
    let picsURL = "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/"
    
    
    
    var delegate: PicsManagerDelegate?
    
    let API_Key = "Your API Key here"
    
    enum OrderBy {
        case latest
        case oldest
        case popular
    }
    
    var searchURL: String {
        return ("\(picsURL)?client_id=\(API_Key)&page=\(String(currentPage))")
    }
    
    func getPics(_ term: String) {
        let fullURL = "\(searchURL)&query=\(term)"
        self.performRequest(with: fullURL)
    }
    
    func performRequest(with urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                
                if let data = data {
                    print("calling parseJSON")
                    self.parseJSON(data)
                    
//                    let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
//                    print(dataString!)
                    
                } else {
                    print("No data!!")
                }
                
                
            })
            
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ picsData: Data) {
        let pics = PicsModel()
        
        do {
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(PicsData.self, from: picsData)
            print("Decoded data:\n\(decodedData.results[0].urls.small)")
            var downloadedPics: [Result] = []
            downloadedPics += decodedData.results
//            print("~~~ ~~~ ~~~")
//            print(downloadedPics)
            for item in decodedData.results {
                let pic = PicDetails(userName: item.user.name, title: item.alt_description, smallPicUrl: item.urls.small, largePicUrl: item.urls.full)
                pics.pics.append(pic)
            }
            
            self.delegate?.didUpdatePics(pics)
            
            
        } catch let error {
            print("Error decoding data: \(error)")
        }
        
    }
}
```

PicsData.swift

```
//
//  PicsData.swift
//  UIKit_ProgrammaticUI_SearchBar
//
//  Created by Matteo on 01/09/2021.
//

import Foundation

struct PicsData: Decodable {
    let total: Int
    let total_pages: Int
    let results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let alt_description: String
    let likes: Int
    let user: User
    let urls: URLS
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

struct URLS: Decodable {
    let thumb: String
    let small: String
    let regular: String
    let full: String
    let raw: String
}
```

PicsModel.swift

```
//
//  PicsModel.swift
//  UIKit_ProgrammaticUI_SearchBar
//
//  Created by Matteo on 05/09/2021.
//

import UIKit

class PicsModel {
    var pics: [PicDetails] = []
    
}

struct PicDetails {
    var userName: String
    var title: String
    var smallPicUrl: String
    var largePicUrl: String
    
//    var smallPicData: UIImageView {
//        return self.getPicData(smallPic)
//    }
    
//    var getShortUserName: String {
//        var nameString = userName
//        nameString = nameString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
//        let start = nameString.index(nameString.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
//        let end = nameString.index(nameString.startIndex, offsetBy: 9)
//        let range = start...end
//        nameString = String(nameString[range])
//        return nameString
//    }
    
    var getUserName: String {
        var nameString = userName
        nameString = nameString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return nameString
    }
    
//    func getPicData(_ urlString: String) -> UIImageView {
//        let img = UIImageView()
//
//        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
//            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
//                let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
//                let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
//                    if error != nil {
//                        img.backgroundColor = .systemRed
//                    }
//
//                    if let data = data {
//                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                            img.image = UIImage(data: data)
//                        }
//                    }
//                })
//                task.resume()
//            }
//        }
//        return img
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Mabus!

You missed a tiny thing that causes your bug, if you go over `setupLayout` method in `CollectionViewCell` class, you would notice that you forgot to add `backgroundImageView` to the content view of the cell.

I have added some lines of code to the `setupLayout` method just to demonstrate what was going wrong, so ignore the aesthetics of the cell :3

```
private func setupLayout() {
        self.contentView.addSubview(roundedBackgroundView)
        roundedBackgroundView.addSubview(picLabel)
        roundedBackgroundView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            roundedBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            roundedBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
            roundedBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            roundedBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            backgroundImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedBackgroundView.centerXAnchor),
            backgroundImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedBackgroundView.centerYAnchor),
            picLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerXAnchor),
            picLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -15)
        ])
    }
```

And this is what your app looks like for now:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe that was the problem. I was so focused looking at the fetching part of the code that I missed that.

Comment: You are welcome. It really does happen sometimes that we get fixated on one point and miss the tiny thing that is causing all the mess. But remember that "The evil is in the details". @mabus